# iOS - How to make scroll with playing movieplayer smooth

Tags: ios, uitableview, video, scroll, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have an app which mostly focuses on videos. But, everytime I scroll while video is playing, it gets a little laggy. I want to ask, how can I make it smooth like Instagram and Vine. 
Thank you for your help.
PS: I used `MPMoviePlayerController` to play my videos.

Here is code I use to play video. Just a small part of the app. Same problem happens when I retrieve video from web services and play them in `UITableView`. When video is playing and I scroll the table view up or down, there is a noticeable lag.

```
NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video1" ofType:@"MOV"];
NSURL *streamURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
[self.moviePlayer setContentURL:streamURL];
```

Comment: how did you play the video on your code?

Comment: Hei, I updated my code from above.

Comment: Use Instruments for finding out where your code is eating resources.